# Check value present in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if certains value present in one column and check in another column using python
if we get data then mark as yes

We have below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a1=["Highschool.sg","school","school.sggs","school.coep","school.mit","address","address.pune","address.Nanded","address.mumbai"]
a2=[34,56,55,34,23,60,34,56,100]
a3=[np.nan,str(["sggs","coep","mit"]),np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,str(["pune","Nanded"]),np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
df =pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a1,a2,a3)),columns=['data','id','required'])
```

[image]

Here  if we get any value like ['sggs','coep','mit'] then need to check in column if any keyword match with this value then mark as YES

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the words (or use any method to get individual strings), concatenate to 'data', and use the list of words to find the matches for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
target = (df['data']+'.'
          +df['required'].str.extractall('(\w+)')[0].droplevel(1)
         ).dropna()
# ['school.sggs', 'school.coep', 'school.mit', 'address.pune', 'address.Nanded']

df.loc[df['data'].isin(target), 'required'] = 'Yes'
```

output:

```
             data   id                 required
0   Highschool.sg   34                      NaN
1          school   56  ['sggs', 'coep', 'mit']
2     school.sggs   55                      Yes
3     school.coep   34                      Yes
4      school.mit   23                      Yes
5         address   60       ['pune', 'Nanded']
6    address.pune   34                      Yes
7  address.Nanded   56                      Yes
8  address.mumbai  100                      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert your string lists to actual lists and operate `str.contains` on the list of exploded values of `df.required`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
required = df.required.dropna().apply(literal_eval).explode()
df.loc[df.data.str.contains('|'.join(required)).values, 'required'] = 'Yes'
```